# Why doesn't function call in Django models refresh values if it includes a db query while other functions work fine?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Here's my code from models.py which only pulls values the first time but not again:

```
def slist():
    return list(set(Product.objects.values_list('servicecat', flat=True)))

class CustomerProduct(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date Data Last Refreshed", default=timezone.now)
    servicecat = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Service Category', null=True, blank=True, choices=tuple(zip(slist(), slist())))
```

It works fine, but it will only pull the values once.  timezone.now works dynamically, but slist() does not.  Why?

Comment: Because you *call* the function, so you store the *result* of the function call in `choices`.

Comment: If you want to recalculate these, you will need to write the logic in the `Form` where you use these.

Comment: That being said, I don't think it is a good idea that choices are derived from another model. If later the `servicecat` of a `Product` changes, then all these `servicecat` fields are no longer valid. It is better to construct a `ServiceCategory` model, and let the `Product` and `CustomerProduct` refer to this (through a `ForeignKey`).

Comment: I should have mentioned this is in models.py.  I understand I can create another database table to resolve this.  I really just wish there were a better way as if I could just dynamically refresh this list I could use the data that's already in the Product table without having to create a new model/table.  This list only changes when new Products are created that have a new "servicecat" in them - in other words a unique list of that field in that table.  I guess there's no getting around either using a new form or creating a new db table.

Comment: you *can* create such list, but it would immediately introduce *another* anti-pattern, and this construction *is* already a huge anti-pattern since it is a *denormalized* database. Denormalized databases tend to be large, slow, have data duplication, and tend not to be able to enforce constraints on the data *by design*.

Comment: @Willem:  isn't timezone.now also being called?  Why is it dynamic but mine is not?  Also, the concern you raise about the servicecat fields no longer being valid - the unique list of that column in the Product table is always the valid list of service categories.  That is the single source of truth for that data and where it originates. EDIT:  I understand though that if I use a new table I can have pointers to that data instead of duplicating it in other tables.  I'm still kind of getting my head around the whole relational model thing.

Comment: Because (a) you do not define a callable, but a vanilla list so what would be called, if you specify `datetime.now`, then Django will *call* that function, so `datetime.now()`, and taht returns the current time, and (b) `choices` are not called, you can use a trick to do that (by overriding the `__init__` of the `Model`), but this will only construct *more* trouble. I would instantly fire an employee that does that, and try to contact his/her school to revoke his/her degree :)

Comment: I think I understand.  Also by the way I don't have any degree in computer science or anything else for that matter and I've only been coding for 3 months in my spare time (this isn't my primary job).  Prior to that I had no coding experience at all.  One of the reasons I keep drifting off in this direction is the way I'm importing my data is via csv files and for every database table that's another csv file I have to import to get back to baseline data.  I think I will figure out a better way to import data as opposed to continuing to have it affect my coding choices.  Thanks for your help.